# Uniqueness in structure theorem for f.g. module over Dedekind domain

Tags: commutative-algebra, exterior-algebra, dedekind-domain

I've been trying to wrap my head around the proof that if $M$ is a finitely generated torsion-free $R$-module over a Dedekind domain $R$, then $M\cong R^n\oplus I$, where $I$ is an ideal of $R$. I'm trying to understand the uniqueness part of the proof, that if $M\cong R^n\oplus I\cong R^m\oplus J$, then $n=m$ and $I$ and $J$ are in the same ideal class.

Showing that $n=m$ I understand.  According to proposition 6.5 of [this source](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/MISC/Dedekind.pdf), we can then look at the determinant map to show $I\cong J$.  Specifically, it mentions looking at $\wedge^{n+1}M$.  Now I know $I$ can be generated by at most two elements.  So it seems like $\wedge^{n+1}M\cong I\oplus\wedge^2I$. If $\wedge^2I$ was trivial, then I understand the isomorphism, but I can't prove that is always the case.  What exactly is May getting at here? How does $\wedge^{n+1}M$ help show $I\cong J$?

Comment: Did you notice the proof in your source asserts that $\det(A \oplus B) = \det(A) \otimes \det(B)$?

Comment: Actually, all one needs is that $\wedge^2 I$ is torsion (which is quite easy) for then $\wedge^{n+1}M\cong I\oplus\text{torsion}$, so $I\cong \wedge^{n+1}M/\text{torsion}$.

Comment: @Hurkyl: Sure, but I still need to understand $det(I)$.  I was originally trying to show there was a projective module $P$ with $I\oplus P\cong R$, which easily finishes the problem, but I'm not convinced such a $P$ always exists.

Comment: @Hempelicious There's a projective module with $I\oplus P\cong R^2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the theorem of exterior algebra that
$${\wedge}^k(A\oplus B)\cong\bigoplus_{j=0}^k\left(\wedge^{k-j} A\right)
\otimes\left(\wedge^j B\right)\tag1.$$
Take $B=I$. Then $\wedge ^0 I=R$ and $\wedge^1I=I$. But I claim
$\wedge^2 I=0$.
Let $I=Ru+Rv$. Then $\wedge^2 I=R(u\wedge v)$ is a cyclic $R$-module.
Now
$$u(u\wedge v)=u\wedge uv=v(u\wedge u)=0$$
and similarly $v(u\wedge v)=0$. So the annihilator of $\wedge^2 I$
contains $I$. But in any ideal class, there is an ideal coprime to
any given ideal. So there is an ideal $J$ coprime to $J$ in the
same ideal class as $I$. Then $I\cong J$ as modules, and $J$
annihilates $\wedge^2J\cong\wedge^2 I$. Thus $I+J=R$
annihilates $\wedge^2 I$, which therefore vanishes.

Now $(1)$ collapses to
$${\wedge}^k(A\oplus I)\cong\left(\wedge^{k} A\right)\oplus
\left(\left(\wedge^{k-1} A\right)\otimes I\right)\tag2.$$
Take $A=R^n$ and $k=n+1$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Your observation in the comments about $\wedge^2I$ being torsion is very elegant!

Comment: I have one question about your argument here (and the comment about torsion): doesn't this imply that if $I$ is a f.g. ideal of any commutative ring $R$, then $\wedge^kI$ is torsion for all $k>1$? Seems like the product of all generators would annihilate all elements.  Is this true?

Comment: I guess actually you don't even need finitely generated to use your argument to show $\wedge^kI$ is torsion for $k>1$. So the argument you gave in your comment shows this cancellation works over any integral domain (so the ideals have no torsion).  Nice!