# Uniqueness for torsion modules over Dedekind domain

Tags: commutative-algebra, localization, dedekind-domain

This is a follow-up to my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2494616/320311), only this time about a finitely generated torsion module $T$ over a Dedekind domain $R$.

What I have done is looked at the prime factorization of $ann(T)\le R$, which looks like $ann(T)=\prod_iP_i^{k_i}$. I then used the Chinese Remainder Theorem to write $T\cong\oplus_iT^{P_i}$, where

$$ T^{P_i}=\{t\in T\mid P_i^{k_t}t=0\text{ for some }k_t\}$$

That is, $T^{P}$ is all the elements in $T$ annihilated by some power of $P$. I then showed that $T\otimes R_{P}\cong T^{P}$ as $R$-modules. I also showed there was an isomorphism as $R_{P}$-modules

$$ T\otimes R_P\cong \oplus_{i=1}^n R_P/P^{e_i} $$
where $e_{i+1}\ge e_i$.

And finally that, as $R$-modules, $R_P/P^{e_i}\cong R/P^{e_i}$.

So to show uniqueness, I have been using the following strategy: if $f(j)=\#(e_i=j)$, then I want to show the function $f$ is an invariant of $T^P$ that doesn't depend on any decomposition. However, all my attempts have failed.  I know $R_P$ is a PID, so I could use the general structure theorem here.  But $R_P$ is a DVR, with only one prime, so it seems like this case should be easier, and doable directly.

Does anyone have any suggestions about how to proceed?